# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to use drawer navigation in new project it show error  `Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.`
I have used in my previous project but here i got this issue

Anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Hermes engine is enabled and add some codes for RNA v2.
   https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/
2. cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && yarn start --reset-cache

Then run: npx react-native run-android

That should fix your issue.